# How to work with conditional dynamically import in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import

I'm trying to make a component which is receiving in the props a string[], iterating over every string, capitalize the string then dynamically import a module of jsx elements, the dependency and directory being "react-icons/si", at the resolve I'm successfully accessing the correct icon. I'm hitting a wall at trying to make that functional component into a proper JSX.Element, because I didn't import using destructuring.

Though Iknow go for the easy route -and probably the best- to just import every icon, I would appreciate any help with an ideia of how to do it and even if is possible.

The dependency of icons I'm working with is react-icons

```
export const TechIcons = ({techs}: TechIconsProps) => {

    function capitalize(word: string):string {
        const lowerCase = word.toLowerCase()
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerCase.slice(1)
    }
    
    let listOfTechs = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < techs.length; i++) {
        const tech = techs[i]
        const techFormated = `Si${capitalize(tech)}`

        import("react-icons/si")
            .then((iconsTech) => {
                console.log(iconsTech[techFormated]
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    return (<>{listOfTechs.join('')}</>)
}
```

One example of that console.log, which is succesfully accessing the jsx element, but I'm unable to make it rendering.

```
f SiNodedotjs(props) {
  return GenIcon({ "tag": "svg", "attr": { "role": "img", "viewBox": "0 0 24 24" }, "child": [{ "tag": "title", "attr": {}, "child": [] }, { "tag": "path", "attr": { "d": "M11.99…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `react-icons/si` is setup for named exports like:

```
import { IconName } from "react-icons/si";
```

You cannot dynamically import named exports. You may only dynamically import entire modules. This is because the `import('path/here')` function does not additionally take a name, only a path.

So dynamically importing any subset of named exports is *not possible.* You must dynamically import the entire module.

So that means you gain no value from a dynamic import. May as well import the whole library statically, and then pull icons from it dynamically. It also, sadly, means that since the bundler can't know what icons you intend to use at runtime, then it must bundle them all which could lead to a lot of extra icons in your bundle that never get used.

---

Import all the icons like this:

```
import * as SI from "react-icons/si"
```

Now `SI` has every named export as properties.

---

Now it seems you want to use a lowercased non-`Si` prefixed version of the name. So we need a type that gets all the icons available, and creates a union of those names.

```
type IconNames = {
  [K in keyof typeof SI]: K extends `Si${infer U}` ? Lowercase<U> : never
}[keyof typeof SI]
// type IconNames = "1001tracklists" | "1password" | "3m" | "42" | "4d" | "500px" | "abbrobotstudio" | "abbvie" | "abletonlive" | "aboutdotme" | "abstract" | "academia" | "accenture" | "acclaim" | ... 2009 more ... | "zyte"
```

This type maps over all the icon names and infers the part of the name after `Si` and then makes it lowercase.

*(Note: this capitalization strategy will not work for any of the icons that start with numbers, like `1Password` or `500Px`. `1password` becomes `1password` instead of the expected `1Password`. I would probably just skip trying to change the icon name case, but that's your call.)*

---

Now we can declare props like this:

```
interface TechIconProps {
  techs: IconNames[]
}
```

And the component like this:

```
function TechIcons({techs}: TechIconProps) {
  const techsFormatted = techs.map(tech => `Si${capitalize(tech)}`) as (keyof typeof SI)[]

  return <>{
    techsFormatted.map((icon, i) => {
      const Icon = SI[icon]
      return <Icon key={i} />
    })
  }</>
}
```

This even gives you autocomplete:

[image: autocomplete]

Note first that a React component *cannot* render asynchronously. It must return JSX immediately. So your `import().then()` can't make it into the render unless it's saved in sate or something. But since we import the icon set statically now, this isn't a problem anymore.

Note second the `const Icon = SI[icon]`. React doesn't consider `<SI[icon] />` to be valid syntax so we stash that icon component to a local variable that makes it easy to render.

[See codesandbox for working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-parm-vqxcm0?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I tried something similar to your answer, but I stubbornly kept with the approach of dynamically import, and also did just like your second note. My choice of capitalize was rather intentional because the plans was to just use icons of our area. When the wall was to much for my current state, I decided to solve this by doing like you said, but instead of import the totality of icons I imported only a certain range of icons and stored in a Map this worked, but there were a problem with the rendering of the icons size. Which led me to just import each icon to represent each project.

Comment: But I would like to point out that it's possible to dynamically import a named export if you are passing a object with the respectively name in the resolve. But this would be opposite of my approach, like: `import(modulepath).then(({name}) => doSomething)`.

Comment: That's importing the entire module and then accessing one of its property. That `import()` line will import _every single icon_ and you end up with a huge object with all icons. `import { Name } from './lib'` imports just that one `Name`, where `import * as Foo from './lib'` and `import('./lib')` import the entire thing. There is a difference.

Comment: Answer updated to clarify that point.